# OleDb returning System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' when using paramaterized SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I keep getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' but i am giving it a value as you can see in my code:

```
private void PopWeapSel(string[] read)
{
    string[] weapID = read;
    string weapDam = "";
    string weapPat = "";
    string weapHeat = "";
    string weapName = "";
    OleDbConnection dbConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=BHShooterProjectDB.accdb");
    string sql = "SELECT ItemWeaponType.WeaponID, ItemWeaponType.WeaponDamage, ItemWeaponType.WeaponPattern, ItemWeaponType.WeaponHeatValue, ItemWeaponType.WeaponCoolRate, ItemWeaponType.WeaponName FROM ItemWeaponType WHERE ItemWeaponTypeWeaponID = @PU;";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
    foreach (string WeapID in weapID)
    {
        if (WeapID == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PU", WeapID); ///Problem Line
        dbConn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            weapDam = reader[1].ToString();
            weapPat = reader[2].ToString();
            weapHeat = reader[3].ToString();
            weapName = reader[4].ToString();
        }
        dbConn.Close();
        this.DGV_WS.Rows.Add(weapDam, weapPat, weapHeat, weapName);
    }
}
```

When i look at the locals in the locals in debug. WeapID has a value of "1" as it should. Have i missed something in terms of syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: I also suspect this code is going to have issues on the second iteration of the `foreach` - since you will have added two parameters (with the same name) to a single `OleDbCommand`. Did you mean to instantiate the `OleDbCommand` **inside** the loop?

Comment: The most obvious cause of this error is that `WeapID` is `null`. The behaviour you are seeing would be expected in that scenario.

Comment: @mjwills if i type "?WeapID" in the immediate window it returns "1". Also moved `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);` inside of the for each. Still get the same error.

Comment: `ItemWeaponTypeWeaponID` is missing a `.`. This is a typo. Voting to close.

Comment: @mjwills Ah thank you so much! Good spot! Looked all the way through my SQL about 10 times.......

Comment: Next time, copy and paste into your database tooling and run it there. This would have shown it was a SQL issue, not a C# issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);` line inside the `foreach` statement.

You are using the same command over and over, and adding more parameters than the query has.

Comment: I tried moving `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);` inside of the for each and the same error still occurs.

Comment: Have you debugged all the way through? When does the exceptions is thrown?